# iPhone app crashes in xmlparser in the middle of nowhere?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

This app has been running fine for months, but now on iOS4 i get crashes when using NSXMLParser. It is crashing in the middle of parsing.

The problem is that i dont get a decent call-stack. the result is:

0 _func__.29470
1 stub helpers

combined with a:
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

in the logs.

I enabled:
NSZombieEnabled
NSDebugEnabled

and i dont get any messages coming out of that, so I guess this is some really nasty memory bug.

Any advice on how to track this down?

Comment: Perhaps some code of your implementation? Also, what XML are you parsing? Is it valid XML? I have noticed too that in iOS4 the NSXMLParserDelegate should be included, but it never made my apps crash not having it. And can you use slog to output to see how far you get. Like do it in didStartElement and output the element name. Might give you a starting point.

Comment: You could also use MallocStackLogging just like with NSZombieEnabled and run the command 
shell malloc_history <pid> <memory address>
In gdb to see a stack of all your threads. 
See http://bit.ly/23ETEF for an example

Comment: The problem just disappeared :/
I m parsing xml from a certain weburl and it seems that whatever caused it to bail out from time to time has disappeared. Very strange ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

there was some weird stuff in my xml in the url attribute:

```
    <relatedArticle url="http://www.xx.yy/dir/7/99/29/&Atilde;Ç&Acirc;&laquo;-cristiano-ronaldo-a-rate-son-mondial-&Atilde;Ç&Acirc;&raquo;/"><![CDATA[Le podcast de Christophe Berti : "Ronaldo a ratÈ son mondial"]]></relatedArticle>
```

This crashed the app. I think it is a bug as in this case NSXMLParser should return an error.